# сложение элементов массива через ассемблерные вставки

Tags: c#, c, ассемблер

Поставили задачу написать алгоритм сложения элементов массива на asm(ассемблерные вставки на с),c#,c и сравнить время исполнения. Написал простенький код для сложения int-ов.

```cpp
double __declspec(dllexport) asm_time(int* array, int N) {
    int* p = array;
    int sum = 0;
    _asm
    {
    
        mov eax, p
        xor ebx, ebx
        mov ecx, 0
    
    cycle:
    
        add ebx, [eax + 4 * ecx]
        inc ecx
        cmp ecx, N
        jne cycle
    
        mov sum, ebx
    
    }
    
    return 1;
}
```

Код вроде бы работает, но при N > 100000000 вылетает исключение:
[[image: введите сюда описание изображения1]

Так же, попытался переписать код под float, которые, как я понял, имеют одинаковый размер с int. Программа так-же падает на порядках 5-6 степени десятки, но в отличие от int, выдает странный результат типа:-4.65661e-10. Так-же есть небольшой вопрос по поводу производительности.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Может ли быть такое? Уж сильно получается asm шустрый, или нужно искать ошибку в алгоритме? Заранее спасибо за ответы

upd:

**кнопка с генерацией массива:**

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int N;

    Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out N);

    int[] array = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rnd.Next(0, 10);
    }
    textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(CObj.getTime(array, N));
    textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(AsmObj.getTime(array, N));
    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(ShapObj.getTime(array, N));
}
```

Передача массива в функцию:

```cs
class testTimeAsm
{
    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\евгений\source\repos\AsmLibrary\Debug\AsmLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern double asm_time(int [] array, int N);
    public double getTime(int [] array, int N)
    {
        var startTime = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        asm_time(array, N);
        startTime.Stop();
        var resultTime = startTime.Elapsed;
        
        return resultTime.TotalMilliseconds;


    }
}
```

Comment: как может работать если всегда `return 1`?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, я возвращал единицу, что бы понять, что программа дошла до конца и не зациклилась. Она ни на что не влияет, так как замеряю время работы цикла  из шарпа. Вывод тестил в отдельном файле, считает правильно на int, на float-ах программа то же что-то считает, но видимо складывает адреса,хотя не могу понять,почему

Comment: Большое подозрение, практически уверенность, что раз у вас переполнение стека - то именно тут и надо искать. Вы свой массив, который суммируете, случайно не в стеке располагаете?...

Comment: Напишите как вызываете функцию, и как передаваемый массив объявляется.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, добавил часть кода в пост, в комментарии не смог отформатировать код

Comment: @Harry, создаю массив через "new", вроде не должен же стек падать

Comment: А после работы не удаляете?..

Comment: @Harry, нет, не удаляю. Что-то даже об этом не думал. Вроде же сборщик мусора все затирает после того, как программа завершается?

Comment: Если на С - то тут "у нищих слуг нет" (с) Жеглов, надо убирать самому. По окончании программы память освободится, но если вы раз 10 ткнете в эту кнопку - то занято будет в 10 раз больше памяти, чем нужно. При N = 100000000 один массив - 400 мегабайт, 10 тыков - и уже 4 Гигабайта... 32-разрядное приложение уже не потянет.

Comment: ну,создаю массив я в c#, в си только отрпавляется указатель на этот массив. Попробовал его(указатель) удалить через delete[], но падает с ошибкой

Comment: можно попробывать присвоение `array = null` или вынести создание массива из метода(один раз использовать `new`) и по клику его перезаполнять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению, я давно слез с x86, но написал небольшой пример, как можно прикруть ассемблер к C#. Дело том, что в x64 все просто с вызовом функций, там только одна конвенция вызова - **fastcall**. Она описана подробнейшим образом [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160).

При этом так как я пишу на ассемблере под **x64**, то **С++** с его примочкой `__asm` для меня закрыт, потому что Visual C++ не поддерживает ассемблерные вставки в x64.

Самое очевидное для меня - использовать [FASM](https://flatassembler.net/).

Далее прямо в редакторе **FASMW** пишу вот такую либу. И собираю в меню **Run->Compile**.

- `CalcArraySum` - для `int[]`
- `CalcArraySumD` - для `double[]`

```
format PE64 console DLL
entry DllEntryPoint

include 'win64a.inc'

section '.text' code readable executable

proc DllEntryPoint hinstDLL,fdwReason,lpvReserved
        mov eax,TRUE
        ret
endp

proc CalcArraySum uses rbx rcx rdx, pArray,dwLength
        mov rbx,rcx
        xor rax,rax
        xor rcx,rcx
     next:
        add eax,[rbx + 4 * rcx]
        inc rcx
        cmp rcx,rdx
        jne next
        ret
endp

proc CalcArraySumD uses rbx rcx rdx, pArray,dwLength
        mov rbx,rcx
        pxor xmm0,xmm0
        xor rcx,rcx
     dnext:
        addsd xmm0,[rbx + 8 * rcx]
        inc rcx
        cmp rcx,rdx
        jne dnext
        ret
endp

section '.edata' export data readable

  export 'Math64.dll',\
         CalcArraySum,'CalcArraySum',\
         CalcArraySumD,'CalcArraySumD'

section '.reloc' fixups data readable discardable

  if $=$$
    dd 0,8              ; if there are no fixups, generate dummy entry
  end if
```

Получаю **Math64.dll** на выходе.

Копирую библиотеку в папку **bin/Debug/net5.0** своего консольного проекта, кстати вот он:

```cs
class Program
{
    private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
    private static readonly int vectorSize = Vector<int>.Count;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 100000000;
        int[] array = Generate(n);
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        int sum = LoopSum(array);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("LoopSum");
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0} Elapsed: {1}ms", sum, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        sum = VectorSum(array);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("VectorSum");
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0} Elapsed: {1}ms", sum, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        sum = AsmSum(array);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("AsmSum");
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0} Elapsed: {1}ms", sum, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        double[] arrayD = GenerateD(n);
        sw.Restart();
        double sumD = LoopSumD(arrayD);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("LoopSumD");
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0} Elapsed: {1}ms", sumD, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        sumD = AsmSumD(arrayD);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("AsmSumD");
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0} Elapsed: {1}ms", sumD, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int[] Generate(int length)
        => Enumerable.Range(default, length).Select(x => rnd.Next(0, 10)).ToArray();

    private static int LoopSum(int[] array)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            result += array[i];
        return result;
    }

    private static int VectorSum(int[] array)
    {
        Vector<int> accVector = Vector<int>.Zero;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= array.Length - vectorSize; i += vectorSize)
            accVector = Vector.Add(accVector, new Vector<int>(array, i));
        return array[i..].Aggregate(Vector.Dot(accVector, Vector<int>.One), (x, y) => x + y);
    }

    [DllImport("Math64.dll")]
    private static extern int CalcArraySum(int[] array, int length);

    private static int AsmSum(int[] array) 
        => CalcArraySum(array, array.Length);

    private static double[] GenerateD(int length)
        => Enumerable.Range(default, length).Select(x => rnd.NextDouble()).ToArray();

    private static double LoopSumD(double[] array)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            result += array[i];
        return result;
    }

    [DllImport("Math64.dll")]
    private static extern double CalcArraySumD(double[] array, int length);

    private static double AsmSumD(double[] array)
        => CalcArraySumD(array, array.Length);
}
```

И получаю вот такой вывод в консоль

```
LoopSum
Result: 449976668 Elapsed: 281ms
VectorSum
Result: 449976668 Elapsed: 112ms
AsmSum
Result: 449976668 Elapsed: 52ms
LoopSumD
Result: 50000545,02830217 Elapsed: 299ms
AsmSumD
Result: 50000545,02830217 Elapsed: 107ms
```

*В качестве развлечения попробовал написать векторный SIMD вариант с использованием `System.Numerics.Vector`. Проект **.NET 5** x64, но должен без проблем отработать и в **.NET Core 3.1**.*

**P.S.** Вот еще одна полезная [ссылка](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/introduction-to-x64-assembly-181178.pdf) про x64 ассемблер, PDF документ на сайте Intel, там тоже упоминается конвенция вызовов, возможно даже более вменяемо описано, чем у Microsoft.

---

Спасибо @AlexanderPetrov. Вот вывод с релизного билда.

```
LoopSum
Result: 449999618 Elapsed: 79ms
VectorSum
Result: 449999618 Elapsed: 30ms
AsmSum
Result: 449999618 Elapsed: 50ms
LoopSumD
Result: 50004374,29094455 Elapsed: 108ms
AsmSumD
Result: 50004374,29094455 Elapsed: 106ms
```

Comment: `Aggregate` - это очень медленно. Цикл `for` будет в несколько раз быстрее.

Comment: bin/Debug - и хорошо бы на Release заменить.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov здесь нет цели упарываться в бенчмарки, иначе я бы использовал `Benchmark.NET`. Понятно дело, что в релизном билде оно отработает значительно быстрее. Задача была показать автору, как прикрутить ассемблер к C# и выжить.

Answer (score 2):

Про ebx сентенцию убрал - и на ответ уже вроде не тянет, но пусть повисит пока.

---

Сложение вещественных чисел осуществляется совсем другими инструкциями (`fadd` на стеке сопроцессора x87 или `addss` для SSE), поэтому не стоит удивляться результату

Кстати, векторное сложение c `padd (int) или addps (float)` будет втрое быстрее, да и умный компилятор должен это сам делать, если уровень оптимизации соответствующий выставлен.

Горизонтальное сложение из коммента - 4 суммы накоплены в xmm1:

```
phaddd xmm1, xmm1
phaddd xmm1, xmm1
movd sum, xmm1
```

Ещё такой момент - для большого размера массива наверняка случится переполнение, результат будет неверен (аналогично и для небольшого массива с крупными числами)

Comment: А откуда такое требование - сохранения `ebx`? Я понимаю `ebp`, `esp` - но `ebx`?... Об этом где-то говорится?

Comment: @Harry В применении ко встроенному ассемблеру VC я неправ, сейчас [When using __asm to write assembly language in C/C++ functions, you don't need to preserve the EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, or EDI registers.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/assembler/inline/using-and-preserving-registers-in-inline-assembly?view=msvc-160), это у меня старые данные, и в calling conventions есть такое правило `The registers RBX, RBP, RDI, RSI, RSP, R12, R13, R14, and R15 are considered nonvolatile (callee-saved)`)

Comment: Как комментарий - в Open Watcom было сделано по-умному: там просто можно было написать, что ты *изменяешь* такие-то регистры, и если компилятору/оптимизатору они нужны - это уже его проблемы сохранять их. Что-то, а встроенный ассемблер там был очень хорошо продуман...

Comment: @MBo, Если не сложно, можете поделится вариантом кода, который выполняет векторное сложение. В интернете не нашел.Спасибо

Comment: @Евгений Назарук Ну у меня только [такое есть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855322/how-do-i-clamp-a-value-into-the-range-really-fast-in-delphi/21855748#21855748) для `Res[i] := A[i] + B[i] with saturation`. В VC++ чаще интринсики используют. Для суммы одного массива с int32 нужно будет сложение paddd, четыре суммы собираются в xmm-регистре, по окончании цикла горизонтальное сложение phaddd

Comment: @MBo, вроде бы разобрался, но возник вопрос по поводу работы phadd.Сумма накпливается в регистре xmm1, там 4 элемента. Делаю phadd sum, xmm1 - вылетает ошибка. делаю к регистру phadd xmm0, xmm1 - такие же четыре элемента в xmm0. Как ее правильно использовать? Спасибо

Comment: @Евгений Назарук В пост добавил.