# Защита приложения на .Net от запуска на неавторизованной машине

Tags: c#

Разрабатываю приложение для работы с зашифрованными данными для использования в приватном сообществе.
Большая часть приложения уже готова. Написана на .Net c использованием паттерна MVVM ибо красиво и удобно.
Передо мной стоит 2 задачи:

1. Защитить используемые в приложении алгоритмы от любопытных глаз. Тут не до абсурда конечно. Просто сделать это крайне не удобным и не доступным для человека с dnSpy, ilSpy и т.д.
2. Постараться минимизировать риск связанный с возможной утечкой приложения в паблик. То есть есть 100 машин на которых это приложение должно работать в офлайне. и если кто-то выкинет это приложение в паблик, то запуск на неавторизованной машине должен также быть не доступен человеку с dnSpy.Такое вот псевдолицензирование.

Мне бы хотелось использовать следующий подход. в моём понимании это должно помочь решить оба вопроса.
Но у меня нет опыта разработки лицензионных приложений, от слова совсем.

1. Оставляем приложение на .Net с MVVM. переносим все "чувствительные" к любопытным глазам алгоритмы на с++.
   То есть делаем либу на с++ с нужными функциями, передаём туда данные из .Net, внутри либы по приватным алгосам это всё считается и возвращает нам нужные данные. Благо все приватные алгоритмы работают с простыми данными типа int и byte.Так что думаю что здесь проблем не должно быть( ну кроме разных библиотек для 32 и 64 бита).
2. В приложение .Net добавляем метод который вытаскивает HardwareId(тут **вопрос 1-й**). Далее этот hwid передается администратору этого приложения у которого есть генератор лицензий к примеру. На основе hwid генерируется файл или код который передаётся пользователю. Пользователь добавляет файл лицензии или вводит данные в приложение и данные сохраняются в реестре. Далее при вызове библиотеки с++ с нашими алгоритмами в функции передается hwid и ключ из реестра. внутри библиотеки с++ происходит проверка на валидность. если проверка прошла, то в .Net приложение возвращаются корректные данные, если проверка не проходит, то возвращается 0 или что-то дефолтное.

Теперь вопросы:

1. Как лучше генерировать hwid на машине. или может использовать какой-то другой метод привязки к компьютеру? Тут в нескольких топиках читал гневные комментарии к привязке к машине по hwid, а-ля горите в аду такие разрабы))))
2. Существуют ли какие-то стандартные для .Net способы лицензирования приложений?
3. Есть ли какие-нибудь источники где можно почитать про стандартные способы лицензирования приложений? Где и как делать проверку. Как лучше не делать и тд.
4. В общих чертах жизнеспособно ли такое решение?(GUI на .net, бизнес логика на с++) Может есть более правильный/простой способ. Как вы считаете?

Ps по поводу обфускаторов для .Net. Так как приложение не планируется продавать, то платные и функциональные версии мне не по карману. А простые варианты с изменением не очень-то и работают. то есть что и как делает алгоритм можно понять с большой долей вероятности.

Pss. Полностью осознаю тот факт что при желании и определённых навыках можно вытащить алгоритмы хоть из ассемблера. Поэтому и хочу сделать только защиту от рефлекторов.

Comment: А вынести на сервер наиболее чувствительные части можно? или только офлайн?

Comment: Применение только офлайн.

Comment: Такое невозможно. C# это открытый язык, с открытым исходным кодом, он очень легко вскрывается даже если есть обфускация или что-либо подобное. Самая надежная защита - выполнять вашу "секретную" логику на стороне сервера, чтоб клиент получал только результат, остальное это ИМХО, детский лепет и мало от чего защитит.

Comment: Скажу по поводу алгоритмов и кода. Я сомневаюсь что у вас какой-то уникальный код, или алгоритм. Так что у вас остаётся только активация. Вот это надо сделать онлайн и держите свой код ген на сервере. Храните ключи активации в недоступных местах и прочее.

Comment: 1) выберите к чему именно на машине вязаться - процу, мамке, харду, и ищите способ получить серийник того, что вам надо, примеров много. 2) нет 3) вопрос из разряда "как просуммировать элементы массива" - сколькими способами вы сможете это сделать? 4) вполне, [хоть на ассемблере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1205597/373567). А так, ваш вопрос подлежит закрытию по 2 критериям: 1) невозможно дать объективный ответ 2) содержит много вопросов, а должен один, необходимо конкретизировать. Голосую за закрытие по второму критерию.

Comment: Дополню, по второму вопросу ответ "нет", потому что если бы существовал стандартный алгоритм лицензирования, существовал бы и стандартный алгоритм взлома. Вспомните системы лицензирвоания старых игр, ко многим подходили стандартные кряки. Так что здесь может помочь только ваш собственный креатив.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ   а .Net Reactor разве не выполняет часть работы по защите? вроде по примерам хорошо скрывает код

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир Если бы было решение, которое было бы способно защитить от сторонних глаз C# код, то наверно многие им бы пользовались и у нас не было так, что каждый проект легко открывался бы и смотрелся. Вот полазайте по интернету и найдите C# проект (игру, программу или что-либо еще), которая не была бы взломана, не валялась на трекерах. Я лично не находил, а если и находил, то там либо 1. это ноунейм программа. 2. У программы все важное на сервере. Да, эти все обфускаторы скроют от большинства ваш код, но если надо будет, то программу на C# мало что спасет.

Comment: Возможно, вас заинтересует это: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ready-to-run

Comment: Несколько вопросов в одном запрещены. По поводу привязки к железу, кое-что есть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1015604/240512 В этом нет ничего особо криминального, просто нужно учитывать, что любую защиту, основанную на этом можно будет обойти созданием виртуальной машины с предопределенными ID устройств.