# Запуск программы c++ из Win Forms c#

Tags: c#, c++

Извиняюсь за неконкретность заданного вопроса, но у меня возникла проблема связанная с двумя языками.
Дело в чем: мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки в Win Forms C#, выполнялся код который нужно как-то написать в c++. Неважно какой код, важно как это сделать?

Как передать клик на кнопку, в код c++ через код c#?

Upd:

В общем, я написал меню на Win Forms. Мне нужно связать C# и C++, то-есть: Нужно написать dll на языке c++, в этой dll, я так полагаю нужно вписать некие параметры, чтобы принять клик по кнопке из проекта C#. Есть кнопка - button1. По нажатию которой, должен выполнится код c++.

Comment: Можно иметь просто 2 разных приложения и запускать одно из другого `Process.Start`. Можно подключить методы из нативной библиотеки, можно много всякого. Вопрос слишком абстрактный.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Upd: познакомьтесь с атрибутом `DllImport`. Он позволяет подключать методы из нативных библиотек. Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1205597/373567), как я подключаю свою нативную библиотеку в C#. Вам по идее нужно то же самое.

Comment: aepot, я в курсе о DllImport. Я уверен вы значительно умнее меня в этой сфере. Можно с вами обсудить мою проблему?

Comment: Можно и без `DllImport` - взять адрес функции и "обернуть" в делегата.

Comment: А что там обсуждать, ссылку на пример я выше кинул, с одной лишь разницей, у меня либа собрана на ассемблере, а у вас на плюсах. Ну и разрядность C# приложения и библиотеки, должны совпадать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По видео этого человека, стало все понятно: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-ass4mkdiA |
Там он показал как создать динамическую библиотеку(dll) c++, и встроить в проект c#.

Я еще порылся на сайтах и нашел парочку нужных мне вещей.

---

Код dll:

```
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __fastcall simple() 
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Text", L"NameOfMessageBox", MB_OK);
}
```

Обязательно ставьте целевую платформу C++ схожую с целевой платформой проекта C# в свойствах проекта. Без этого проект будет **крашиться**!

Чтобы собрать dll:
В диспетчере конфигураций выберите "Release", далее сверху на панели будет пункт "Сборка", далее "Собрать решение". И в корневой папке: название вашего приложения\Release\name.dll.

---

Код  C#:

Импорт dll теперь выглядит так -

```
[DllImport(@"..\..\..\name.dll")]
public static extern void simple();
```

Ну и запустить эту функцию:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        simple();
    }
```

У меня по кнопке, но можно и с другими событиями.

**Где simple - это название вписанной в dll функции**

Comment: `Обязательно ставьте целевую платформу x86 в свойствах проекта c++` я же вам русским по белому написал - целевая платформа у C# и C++ проекта должна быть одинаковая. Хоть x86, хоть x64, главное - и там и там ОДИНАКОВАЯ. А у вас наверняка в C# стоит Any CPU, а это соответствует x86 для нативок. Так что выше указанное утверждение неверно, вводите читателей в заблуждение. Да, кстати, для x64 конвенция вызова fastcall должна быть, видимо потому что вы stdcall прописали, поэтому и не завелось на x64. Исправьте ответ.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь, я очень вам благодарен. Заранее прошу простить, я на форумах новый персонаж, так что для меня это все в новинку.  И программирование я изучаю только для себя, и ради одной цели, по этому для меня рабочий результат, превосходит другие.

Comment: получилось x64? Можно кстати шибу положить в один каталог с запускаемым файлом приложения, тогда можно будет импортировать просто вот так `DllImport("name.dll")`

Comment: У меня прога поделена на каталоги, типо в разных частях, для перемещения между томами одного файла