# Простой интерпретатор ассемблера. Где можно об этом подробно почитать?

Tags: c#, ассемблер

Необходимо написать интерпретатор, который работает с 4 командами и регистрами (C#).

Помогите с информацией по данному направлению, может есть электронная книга или хорошая статья?

We want to create a simple interpreter of assembler which will support the following instructions:

mov x y - copies y (either a constant value or the content of a register) into register x
inc x - increases the content of the register x by one
dec x - decreases the content of the register x by one
jnz x y - jumps to an instruction y steps away (positive means forward, negative means backward, y can be a register or a constant), but only if x (a constant or a register) is not zero
Register names are alphabetical (letters only). Constants are always integers (positive or negative).

Note: the jnz instruction moves relative to itself. For example, an offset of -1 would continue at the previous instruction, while an offset of 2 would skip over the next instruction.

The function will take an input list with the sequence of the program instructions and will execute them. The program ends when there are no more instructions to execute, then it returns a dictionary (a table in COBOL) with the contents of the registers.

Also, every inc/dec/jnz on a register will always be preceeded by a mov on the register first, so you don't need to worry about uninitialized registers.

Например:

["mov a 5"; "inc a"; "dec a"; "dec a"; "jnz a -1"; "inc a"]

visualized:

mov a 5

inc a

dec a

dec a

jnz a -1

inc a

The above code will:

set register a to 5,
increase its value by 1,
decrease its value by 2,
then decrease its value until it is zero (jnz a -1 jumps to the previous instruction if a is not zero)
and then increase its value by 1, leaving register a at 1

Соответственно, функция должна возвращать следующее:

```
new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a" , 1 } };
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/badoo/blog/425325/
https://habr.com/ru/post/434138/

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43176/How-to-create-your-own-virtual-machine

Comment: симулятор процессора чтоли? учебное задание? или что-то такое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1205597/373567 ? какими командами? какими регистрами? ассемблер - компилируемый язык, интерпретировать можно его только симуляцией.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я скорректировал информацию. Есть вот такие исходники. Вот вся конкретика.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, вы издеваетесь, что ли? Для такого задания столько чтива (практически не нужного ему) предложили?

Comment: Так, и что тогда необходимо, по Вашему мнению?

Comment: @avp, главное что выбор есть. Фильтрацию информации никто не отменял. И необязательно все читать. Предложите ссылки лучше.

Comment: Да, я все равно говорю спасибо Вам Tiger за ссылки, почитать все равно будет не лишним, но и мнение avp хотел бы услышать.

Comment: Тут все просто. Регистры это массив из 4-х элементов целого типа, индексируемый номером регистра (просто переводите буквы в номера -- a - 0, b - 1, c - 2, d - 3).  Затем, вам нужно моделировать память команд. Например, подойдет массив структур. Первый элемент сруктуры это код операции (вообще-то достаточно 2 бита), второй -- целое число, скажем int. / Ваш код  состоит из 2-х частей. Первая -- чтение текста программы, распознавание инструкций и последовательное заполнение памяти команд. Вторая часть -- исполнение программы (уже скомпилированной) из памяти. Думаю, это вы сами уже сообразите

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOSwChQXfEs

Comment: @TosterIsMyCredo, пардон, посмотрел повнимательней -- заметил вот это `mov x y - copies y (either a constant value or the content of a register)`. По сути уточнение, что вторым операндом mov может быть регистр, делит mov на 2 кода -- mov (второй операнд число) и movr (второй операнд регистр). Тогда операций становится уже 5 (и для кода операции нужно 3 бита) Для номера регистра по прежнему нужно 2 бита. Естественно, вы можете обе эти величины (3 бита кода операции и 2 бита номера регистра первого операнда) хранить вместе в первом элементе структуры, представляющей память программы

Comment: В прииере в вопросе не x86 ассемблер, а что-то выдуманное, или другой какой-то неизвестный мне ассемблер, поэтому здесь сложно предложить что-либо читать по выдуманному языку. Просто забудьте, что это ассемблер, и реализуйте остальные требования.

Comment: @aepot, вы привязали себя к x86-архитектуре и теперь пожинаете плоды непонимания. Абстракция проста - есть процессор, в котором есть регистры, и есть набор команд по манипуляции значениями этих регистров. И да, команды можно выдумывать.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru я писал инструкции еще под Z80, так что не надо мне ставить диагнозы. Спасибо.

Comment: так я прочитал все что вы все написали и благодарю вас. Прошу не ругайтесь, у всех своё мнение на эту тему(весьма неоднозначную). Единственное попрошу показать хотя бы одну реализацию 1 регистра и 1 команды. Чтобы я пока копаюсь, смог уже наглядно представлять, что мне нужно делать с остальными. Спасибо  заранее и за вашу активность.

Comment: В ютубе решение есть, просто повтори ручками - может что в голове отложится.

Comment: TigerTV.ru, спасибо за свежую ссылку от 8 августа на разбор этого Ката, очень информативно и подробно. Даже подписался на него, настолько он хорошо объясняет. Вот только у меня главный вопрос, что нужно писать в Main() ? Или где можно почитать про то, как это оборачивают в Main по итогу. Потому у него как короткое решение, так и подробное описано без Main.